# angularjs - select image from dropdown list (button)

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to select an image from the dropdown list (stored in a button), with angularJS. I am not using  with options as these can only be used with text. All the solutions I find seem to be for select, and not for a button.
Does someone know how to get round this?

```
<div id="dropdown" class="dropdown" ng-model="payment.image">
    <button id="dropdown-btn" class="btn btn-default form-control ui-select-toggle" ng-click="toggle = !toggle" aria-labelledby="dropdown-btn">
        <img src="{{icons[0]}}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
        <div class="dropdown-content" ng-repeat="icon in icons" ng-if="$index>0">
            <a href="#" ng-class="{'show':toggle}" ng-init="{'show'=false}">
                <img ng-src="{{ icon }}" ng-click="select(icon)">
            </a>
        </div> . 
    </button>
</div>

function ($translate, $scope, PaymentMethodService) {
    'use strict';
    $scope.icons = [];

    $scope.dropDown = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            $scope.icons.push('static/images/BBICON_' + [i + 1] + '.png');
        }
        console.log($scope.icons);
    };

    $scope.dropDown;
```

Comment: P.S. This is Angular version 1.4!! A little old..

Comment: Also, we're not using jQuery in the project. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing here ?

Comment: I want to be able to use the dropdown button as if it were a select menu with options. I.e I want to be able to select an image without being redirected (since they are not options, but anchor tags instead).

Answer (score 0):

Here I have made some changes. 
`ng-init="{'show': false}"` removed from HTML and added `$scope.toggle = false` into controller.

```js
angular.module("app",[]).controller("MainController", function($scope) {
    $scope.toggle = false;
    $scope.icons = [];

    $scope.dropDown = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            $scope.icons.push('static/images/BBICON_' + [i + 1] + '.png');
        }
       // console.log($scope.icons);
    };

    $scope.dropDown();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">
<div id="dropdown" class="dropdown" ng-model="payment.image">
    <button id="dropdown-btn" class="btn btn-default form-control ui-select-toggle" ng-click="toggle = !toggle" aria-labelledby="dropdown-btn">
        <img src="{{icons[0]}}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
        <div class="dropdown-content" ng-repeat="icon in icons" ng-if="$index>0">
            <a href="#" ng-class="{'show':toggle}">
                <img ng-src="{{ icon }}" ng-click="select(icon)">
            </a>
        </div> . 
    </button>
</div>

</div>
```